# Azure Pipeline: AzureCli@ task throwing: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation:

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-pipelines, azure-service-principal

I am creating a **DevOps** pipeline for a NodeJs app which i am containerizing as a Docker Image in ACR and deploying it as a ContainerApp in Azure.

I have the following permissions in subscription : > User Access Administrator ( cannot be given more elevated permissions other than this)

I have already created a App Registration -> AppReg1- which i will patch the containerapp url in the pipleline

For deploying from ACR, I am writing a pipeline job as a bash script:

```
variables:
  # Container registry service connection established during pipeline creation
  armDeploymentServiceConnection: 'appdeploy1' //passing the service connection name here
```

```
- stage: DeployContainerApp
  displayName: Deploy the Image as a Container app
  jobs:
  - job: DeployContainerApp
    displayName: Deploy Container App Job
    steps:
    - task: AzureCLI@2
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: $(armDeploymentServiceConnection) //passing service connection name
        scriptType: 'bash'
        scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
        inlineScript: |
          az --version
          az account show
          echo "containerapp  will be created"
          az ad app show --id $(AppReg1ClientId) --query id | jq -r . //error line throwing insufficient privileges
```

in the inputs: I have created a ARM type service connection with manual Service principal defined
`inputs: azureSubscription:**armDeploymentServiceConnection**:` //Here I am passing the ServiceConnection which i have created in manual mode:
[image]

The SP i used for this Service connection **appdeploy1** is created with the role **contributor** before hand

`az ad sp create-for-rbac --scopes /subscriptions/xxxx --role Contributor --name **appSP**`

This SP leads to a additional AppRegistration ex->**appSP**. I am using this SP only for the inline script

When i run the pipeline, this line throws this error where i m trying to get the object id of the registration AppReg1 where i am going to register my containerApp:
`az ad app show --id $(AppReg1ClientId) --query id | jq -r .`

```
ERROR: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
```

Since i created the service principal with the role **contributor** and created the ServiceConnection with that principal **appSP**
i thought this step will succeed:

```
 - task: AzureCLI@2
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: $(armDeploymentServiceConnection)
```

but this line throws error
`inlineScript: | az ad app show --id $(APP_REG_CLIENT_ID) --query id | jq -r . //error line`

I am not sure, what is missing here? Can anyone please help?

Comment: Did you try using task AzureWebAppContainer to deploy rather than a CLI command? Also did you try letting the pipeline creating the service connection for you?

Answer (score 0):

Service connections are created under subscription/resource group, as the contributor, it owns Grants full access to manage all resources in the subscription.

However, app exists in Azure AD so you need enough permission in AAD to list it. Since they are in different scope, you need to sign in as the AAD identity then run the 'az ad app show --id' command.

Please kindly try to use things like this to have a try:

```
- task: AzureKeyVault@1
  inputs:
    ConnectedServiceName: **
    KeyVaultName: **
    SecretsFilter: 'secretUser,secretPassword'
    RunAsPreJob: true 
- pwsh: 
    az login -u $(secretUser) -p $(secretPassword)
    az --version
    az account show
    echo "containerapp  will be created"
    az ad app show --id *** --query id | jq -r
```

You could also try to add the secrets 'secretUser and secretPassword' in library-variable group and use it in your yaml for singing in as a user.

Hope this could help.

Comment: Thank you. but i dont want to login with the user context

Answer (score 0):

> Insufficient privileges to complete the operation:

This error means that the service principal has no access to AAD application when running the commnad: `az ad app show`

When you grant the Contributor Role to your service principal, it is at Azure Subscription Level instead AAD.

To solve this issue, you need to grant the Service Principal **Directory readers Role** or higher permissions in **Azure Portal -> Azure Active Directory -> Roles and administrators -> Select the target role and add the user**.

For example:

[image]

Then you can run the azure cli command:`az ad app show`  successfully.

**Update:**

Another method is that you can set the
**Application.Read.All** or **Application.ReadWrite.All** scope for the Service Principal in **AAD -> Target Service Principal -> API Permission -> Search Microsoft Graph -> Application.**

Here is an example:

[image]

Then you need to click the option:**Grant Admin consent for xxx Directory**  to apply the API permission.

Comment: Thank you, but my role is just Your Role:
User So I will not be able to assign the role as I a just user access administrator as stated higher privileges would not be given

Comment: You can contact the admin of the AAD to grant the directory reader role to your service principal. Then the Azure CLI will work.

Comment: @Coder Another method is set the Application scope in Service Principal -> API Permission ->Microsoft Graph . It will work too. Refer to my update.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Windows agent with bash, you will get this error. Try with a Linux agent instead.